# Compact resolvent

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Given that the operator
$$
Hf(x) = -xf''(x) + (x - 1)f'(x) 
$$
on the Hilbert space $L^2([0,\infty),e^{-x}dx)$ possesses, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, an eigenvalue $\lambda_n = n$ with eigenvector the Laguerre polynomial of degree $n$, how can I deduce that the self adjoint operator
$$
Kf(x) = Hf(x) + \frac{1}{3} \sin(x)f(x)
$$
has a compact resolvent?

Comment: Do you mean say, how to show that $R(z) = (K - z \mathrm{Id})^{-1}$ is a compact operator for some $z$?

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a selfadjoint operator with compact resolvent, then bounded perturbation of it will have compact resolvent too. This can be seen like this: let me use the notation $Bf(x)=\frac{1}{3}\sin x f(x)$, then

$$(\lambda-H-B)= (I-B(\lambda-H)^{-1})(\lambda-H)$$.

Because of selfadointness, if $\lambda\in i\mathbb{R}$ is large enough (i.e., $\Im\lambda>\|B\|$), then $\|B(\lambda-H)^{-1}\|<1$, and hence

$$(\lambda-H-B)^{-1} = (\lambda-H)^{-1}(I-B(\lambda-H)^{-1})^{-1},$$

which is the product of a compact and a bounded operator.